# Removing duplicate whitespace in title when using yt-dlp

Tags: youtube-dl, yt-dlp

I have a set of videos I'm trying to download but they often have large quantities of whitespace in the video title. However, I want to have the titles named correctly in the downloaded filename (just without the additional whitespace).

I think this can be achieved with a postprocessor but I'm not sure how to implement it.

I had this command written down somewhere from a while back but it doesn't work now. Not sure if it ever did;

```
yt-dlp.exe "url" --postprocessor "re_replace: '\s+', ' ', 'title'" -o D:\download\%(upload_date)s_%(title)s.%(ext)s
```

But I get the error;

```
yt-dlp.exe: error: no such option: --postprocessor "re_replace: '\s+', ' ', 'title'"
```

Comment: Please remove [ytdl] tag, it's for a node.js module

Comment: @pierpy Done! Sorry I didn't realise

Answer (score 0):

The switch `--postprocessor` does not exists.
It's `--postprocessor-args`

**EDIT:**
After your clarifying comment, there is no way to obtain that directly from `yt-dlp`. You have to write separate code, maybe using the `--exec` switch and piping the filename to a robust utility like [rename](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) on Linux, or the Powershell [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.3) on Windows

Comment: I still couldn't get that to work so I just wrapped the command in a python function and renamed the files after. Would still be glad to see a solution though!